# SQL - Find duplicate fields and count how many fields are matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates

I have a a large customer database where customers have been added multiple times in some circumstances which is causing problems. I am able to use a query to identify the records which are an exact match, although some records have slight variations such as different addresses or given names.

I want to query across 10 fields, some records will match all 10 which is clearly a duplicate although other fields may only match 5 fields with another record and require further investigation. Therefore i want to create a results set which has field with a count how many fields have been matched. Basically to create a rating of the likely hood the result is an actual match. All 10 would be a clear dup but 5 would only be a possible duplicate.

Some will only match on POSTCODE and FIRSTNAME which is generally can be discounted.

Something like this helps but as it only returns records which explicitly match on all 3 records its not really useful due the sheer amount of data.

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3, count(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY field1,field2,field3
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do this. You could do your regular join criteria and then for each column use a case expression. case when table1.field1 = table2.field2 then 1 end...repeat for each column. Then you can easily tell how many columns matched.

Comment: How large is the set of potential customers thousands, millions, ??

Comment: Just to be clear:  You're wanting each row to be compared to all other rows, in order to determine a 'count' for how many columns are exact matches?  You're talking about a cross-join there (where the primary keys are not the same, for those will always be complete matches), which will be grossly expensive if there's more than a thousand rows or so.

Comment: @pmbAustin you don't need a cross join if you use the right grouping sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the magic of [`CUBE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which generates all the combinations of columns automatically

```
DECLARE @duplicate_column_threshold int = 5;

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    field1,field2,...,field10
   ,duplicate_column_count = (SELECT COUNT(col) FROM (VALUES (field1),(field2),...,(field10)) c(col))
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY CUBE(field1,field2,...,field10)
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT *
INTO #duplicated_rows
FROM cte
WHERE duplicate_column_count >= @duplicate_column_threshold
```

---

Update: to fetch the rows from the original table, join it against the #duplicated_rows using a technique that treats NULLs as wildcards when comparing the columns.

```
SELECT
  a.* 
 ,b.duplicate_column_count
FROM table_name a 
INNER JOIN #duplicated_rows b
  ON  NULLIF(b.field1,a.field1) IS NULL
  AND NULLIF(b.field2,a.field2) IS NULL
  ...
  AND NULLIF(b.field10,a.field10) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Anon, its works well and I'm able to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Is it possible to return the Customer ID fields which are matched in the above query. The customer ID is always unique, would be helpful to return these values as well.

Comment: Thanks Anon, this has helped. When i run the Query with the intersect it takes an age, i left it running and after 1.5 hrs it returns some result but was still running so i stopped. I also loose the duplicate_column_count is there a way to retain this within the results.

Comment: But you have answered my original question, so thank you for sharing your knowledge. I'm now able to return results with a count of the number of fields which are duplicated. returning the additional fields would be useful but a nice to have at this stage.

Comment: Updated again to avoid the INTERSECT

Comment: Is there a way to tune the results to only display unique customer ids. As when i run duplicate_column_count >= @duplicate_column_threshold it will show up multiple times for the same record as it has 4, 5 & 6 matching fields.

Comment: At the moment I'm putting the results into a temp table and then running another query to display on unique cust ID's

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like

```
Select field1, field2, field3, ... , field10, count(1)
  from customerdatabase
 group by field1, field2, field3, ... , field10
 order by field1, field2, field3, ... , field10
```

Where `field1` through `field10` are ordered by the "most identifiable/important" to least.

Comment: This may help, but I'm hoping to create a query as described which rates each duplicate with a count of the fields matched. As we need to submit the database to a regulator on a regular basis so the table needs to be checked before every submission to ensure no duplicates exist. As its quite large we need to ensure this is as user friendly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close I've got to what i'm trying to achieve, which will return all records which have any duplicate fields. I want to add a column to the results which indicate how many fields have matched any other record in the table. There are around 40,000 records in total.

```
select * from [CUST].[dbo].[REPORTA] as a
where exists
(select [GIVEN.NAMES],[FAMILY.NAME],[DATE.OF.BIRTH],[POST.CODE],[STREET],[TOWN.COUNTRY]
   from [CUST].[dbo].[REPORTA] as b
   where a.[GIVEN.NAMES] = b.[GIVEN.NAMES]
     or a.[FAMILY.NAME] = b.[FAMILY.NAME]
      or a.[DATE.OF.BIRTH] = b.[DATE.OF.BIRTH]
      or a.[POST.CODE] = b.[POST.CODE]
      or a.[STREET] = b.[STREET]
       or a.[TOWN.COUNTRY] = b.[TOWN.COUNTRY]
   group by [GIVEN.NAMES],[FAMILY.NAME],[DATE.OF.BIRTH],[POST.CODE],[STREET],[TOWN.COUNTRY]
   having count(*) >= 1)
```

This query will return thousands of records but I'm generally interested in the record with a high count of exactly matching fields